# Capturing Outlook Email Send Time In Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

An Outlook email is generated whenever I execute a VBA code in Excel. It does not automatically send, nor do I want it to. The email is populated by cell values in a range (which are based off of the ActiveCell) and **I want to programmatically capture when the email is manually sent** into ActiveCell.Offset(0, 13), preferably with VBA in my current Excel program.

This is the code by which I display the email:

```
'Send Stock Request:
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With OutMail
    .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    .HTMLBody = "My eMail's HTML Body"
    .To = "myrecipients@theiremails.com"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Stock Request"
    .Display
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
```

Comment: If not possible in Excel vba (I dont know if it is possible or not) then maybe use Outlook vba. There is a Send event where you could check which email you are sending, and store the information in Excel.

Comment: In that case, do you know how would I access that event? I am familiar with Excel's object model but not Outlook's unfortunately.

Comment: Is the Excel file guaranteed to be open when the mail is finally sent?

Comment: Yes it will be open throughout the entire process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done through VBA, but code below must be pasted in Outlook module instead of Excel, in `Outlook`=>`ThisOutlookSession` module. Also, make sure you allow macros in Outlook.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal olItem As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim Xl As Object ' Excel.Application
Dim Wb As Object ' Excel.Workbook
Set Xl = GetObject(, "excel.application")
Set Wb = Xl.Workbooks("NameOfYourOpenedWorkbook.xlsb")
Wb.Activate
Xl.activecell.Offset(0, 13).Value = Date & " " & Time

End Sub
```

So now when you send your automatically created email manually, you will get date and time captured in your opened Workbook in `ActiveCell.Offset(0, 13)` cell.

Comment: Thank you very much for that! I will try to implement this and let you know what happens. Will this affect all sent emails or only the ones created through the Excel modules (if that answer is obvious then please forgive my overlooking it as I have minimal experience with VBA in Outlook)?

Comment: This worked beautifully! Thank you very much for your help with that!

Comment: You're welcome. Good question, it will affect all send emails. you could add if statement inside private sub to only run rest of the code when your specific workbook is opened. or simply disable macros in outlook when not working with your excel file...

Comment: That's what I thought but wanted to make sure. I think adding the IF statement to check the subject of the email and that the workbook is open will pretty well solve this for me. Again, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Add a VBA project reference to the Outlook object model, and add this class to your excel file:

```
''clsMail
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents itm As Outlook.MailItem
Public DestCell As Range '<< where to put the "sent" message
'you can add other fields here if you need (eg) to 
'  preserve some other info to act on when the mail is sent

Private Sub itm_Send(Cancel As Boolean)
    Debug.Print "Sending mail with subject: '" & itm.Subject & "'"
    DestCell.Value = "Mail sent!"  '<< record the mail was sent
End Sub
```

Then in your Mail-sending code you can do something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Dim colMails As New Collection

Sub Tester()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim obj As clsMail

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With OutMail
       .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
       .HTMLBody = "My eMail's HTML Body"
       .To = "twilliams@theravance.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Stock Request"
        .Display
    End With
    'create an instance of the class and add it to the global collection colMails
    Set obj = New clsMail
    Set obj.itm = OutMail
    Set obj.DestCell = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 13) '<< "sent" flag goes here
                                                ' when the user sends the mail
    colMails.Add obj

End Sub
```