# Capturing Outlook Email Sent Time From HTML

Tags: javascript, html, vba, outlook

An Outlook email is generated whenever I click a button in my Webpage (created using basic HTML and JS). It does not automatically send, nor do I want it to.
I want to programmatically capture when the email is manually sent into My Webpage table.

Can I do this from Outlook VBA as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46307867)? ( If I can please explain how, as that answer is only for excel )

Or any way to do from my webpage itself without using any external libraries or packages?

Possible Tools that I can use are:

- HTML
- Basic JS
- VBA
- ACCESS DB

Note: I don't have privileges' to install packages.

Is this something possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot do that - the best you can do is to show a new message (either using a `mailto` link or by creating a new EML file), but since you cannot (generally) run any client side code and cannot interact with Outlook from a webpage script, you cannot hook up the `Application.ItemSend` event.

You can of course add your own email address to CC or BCC and then process the incoming message on your server, but I am not sure the end users will like that and they can always remove that recipient from the message when it is displayed.